# Howto custom figure with counter w/o using figure-environment

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, counters

I am trying to create a visually more appealing figure, that looks like the output of the MWE below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand{\CustomFigure}[3][.4\textwidth]
{
  \stepcounter{figure}
  %\captionof{figure}[The caption.]{}
  \begin{tikzpicture}    
    \draw (0,0) node(origin) {}; 
    %rectangle (.4\textwidth,40mm);
    \draw (origin.west) +(4pt,-8pt) node(caporg){}; 
    \draw [blue, fill=blue] (caporg.south) +(0.0,0.0) -- +(0.09,0.18) -- +(0.18,0) node (arroweast){} -- cycle;
    \draw [font=\sffamily\bfseries,blue] (arroweast.east) +(-2pt,+10pt) node[anchor=north west](caption) {　Figure \thefigure};
    \draw [font=\sffamily,black,text justified, text width=#1] (caporg.south west) +(-1pt,-2pt) node[anchor=north west](description)
    {
      \mdseries #3
    }; 
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] (image) (origin.north west)
      {\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{#2}}; 
      \label{fig:NFb}
  \end{tikzpicture}


} % \CustomFigure ENDS


\begin{document}

\newgeometry{top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,headsep=10pt}

\kant[7] 
Some more lipsum.\newline

\begin{figure}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-a};
    \caption{Just a figure.}
    \label{fig:NFa}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}

\CustomFigure{example-image-b}{\textbf{Header text.} The crazy monkey jumped over the sleeping lion. He met quick brown fox from his own lipsum.}

See figures '\ref{fig:NFa}' and '\ref{fig:NFb}'  for details. 

\newpage
\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

'example-image-a' is a figure as usual. Works of course.

Now the output of 'CustomImage' produces the desired visual outcome, but the list of figures is screwed up. It only shows the 'real' figure but not the custom-figure. 
(Btw. CustomFigure is not an environment because it would not draw more than a single char of the text.)

I though this could be solved by adding a `\captionof{figure}[The caption.]{}` (which it does indeed) but then there would also be the caption itself placed as well. Is there a way to JUST set the caption for \thefigure (the figure stepped with stepcounter) invisibly, without the need to use captionof?

The list of figures must show the content of the 'hidden' caption of course.

Or do I need to re-implement `\listoffigures` myself?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `\captionlistentry{figure}{Something}`.

Comment: @Johannes_B doesn't work with the MWE. (Undefined control sequence). Do I need to add some additional packages?

Comment: you also need `\refstepcounter` not `\stepcounter` if you want `\label` to work.

Comment: @David Yes, thanks. That solved one error. But the 'List of Figures' still wont show and figures. I guess because no captions are defined for them, right?

Comment: @Edward: Since neither `\caption` nor `\captionof` is used/wanted, nothing writes information to the `.lof` file. You have to add it manually with `\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\thefigure~}Your caption text}`, where `Your caption text` seems to be `#3` here

Comment: @Christian OUTSTANDING! That really did it right away. Unbelievable. You should have posted an answer... how am I going to close this post now?

Comment: @Edward: I will answer

Comment: You should place `\label` inside of the `#3` argument, otherwise you would have multiple `fig:Nfb` labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since neither `\caption` nor `\captionof` are wanted/used, no command writes something to the `.lof` file -- `\CustomFigure` will not make entries to the `.lof` file.

Those have to be done manually with `\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\thefigure}#4}` where `#4` is the caption text which is from an optional 4th argument which defaults to `#3` if it is not specified. (see the 3rd usage).

`\refstepcounter` usage has been suggested by David Carlisle already.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{caption}

\NewDocumentCommand{\CustomFigure}{O{.4\textwidth}+m+m+O{#3}}{%
  \refstepcounter{figure}
  %\captionof{figure}[The caption.]{}
  \begin{tikzpicture}    
    \draw (0,0) node(origin) {}; 
    %rectangle (.4\textwidth,40mm);
    \draw (origin.west) +(4pt,-8pt) node(caporg){}; 
    \draw [blue, fill=blue] (caporg.south) +(0.0,0.0) -- +(0.09,0.18) -- +(0.18,0) node (arroweast){} -- cycle;
    \draw [font=\sffamily\bfseries,blue] (arroweast.east) +(-2pt,+10pt) node[anchor=north west](caption) {　Figure \thefigure};
    \draw [font=\sffamily,black,text justified, text width=#1] (caporg.south west) +(-1pt,-2pt) node[anchor=north west](description)
    {
      \mdseries #3%
      \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\thefigure}#4}%
    }; 
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] (image) (origin.north west)
      {\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{#2}}; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
} % \CustomFigure ENDS


\begin{document}

\newgeometry{top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,headsep=10pt}

\kant[7] 
Some more lipsum.\newline

\begin{figure}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-a};
    \caption{Just a figure.}
    \label{fig:NFa}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}

\CustomFigure{example-image-b}{\label{fig:NFb}\textbf{Header text.} The crazy monkey jumped over the sleeping lion. He met quick brown fox from his own lipsum. }

\CustomFigure{example-image-b}{\label{fig:NFc}\textbf{Header text.} The crazy monkey jumped over the sleeping lion. He met quick brown fox from his own lipsum.}[And some shorter Text]

See figures '\ref{fig:NFa}' and '\ref{fig:NFb}'  for details. 

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Version without `\NewDocumentCommand`**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand{\CustomFigure}[3][0.4\textwidth]{%
  \refstepcounter{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}    
    \draw (0,0) node(origin) {}; 
    %rectangle (.4\textwidth,40mm);
    \draw (origin.west) +(4pt,-8pt) node(caporg){}; 
    \draw [blue, fill=blue] (caporg.south) +(0.0,0.0) -- +(0.09,0.18) -- +(0.18,0) node (arroweast){} -- cycle;
    \draw [font=\sffamily\bfseries,blue] (arroweast.east) +(-2pt,+10pt) node[anchor=north west](caption) {　Figure \thefigure};
    \draw [font=\sffamily,black,text justified, text width=#1] (caporg.south west) +(-1pt,-2pt) node[anchor=north west](description)
    {
      \mdseries #3%
      \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\thefigure}#3}%
    }; 
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] (image) (origin.north west)
      {\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{#2}}; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
} % \CustomFigure ENDS


\begin{document}

\newgeometry{top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,headsep=10pt}

\kant[7] 
Some more lipsum.\newline

\begin{figure}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-a};
    \caption{Just a figure.}
    \label{fig:NFa}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}

\CustomFigure{example-image-b}{\label{fig:NFb}\textbf{Header text.} The crazy monkey jumped over the sleeping lion. He met quick brown fox from his own lipsum. }

\CustomFigure{example-image-b}{\label{fig:NFc}\textbf{Header text.} The crazy monkey jumped over the sleeping lion. He met quick brown fox from his own lipsum.}

See figures '\ref{fig:NFa}' and '\ref{fig:NFb}'  for details. 

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

Comment: This MWE does not compile with y MikTex, "Illegal parameter number in definition of \_xparse_grab_arg"

Comment: @Edward: It compiles for me out of the box

Comment: I do believe you :-) Maybe somethings' wrong with my latex. Wouldn't be the first time. Care to provide an alternative solution NOT based on xparse?

Comment: @Edward: Yes, but you will lose the optional 4th argument then

Comment: Ahh, yes. That problem. I already got used to it. I would keep your first solution (xparse) for future reference and the usual \newcommand solution as default/fallback.

Comment: @Edward: Updated

Comment: Yes, the second version definitely works for me. Thanks. I have marked this answer.